# Consuming Windows Authenticated Service for Client Development in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, windows-authentication

I have a service hosted in server. The service authentication is using Windows Authentication. I want to use this service in my website development in Visual Studio 2010. When I try to add a reference it says the following error.

```
“Security settings for this service require Windows Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.”
```

What should I do to overcome it and be able to consume the service for development?

Note: The error message is obvious. What I am looking for is the best way to overcome this.

Note: When I type the service address in Mozilla Firefox, it asks for my windows credentials -upon entering credentials it gives me the service descriptions. The problem is when I use it via Visual Studio.

---

Comment: Are you testing this via IIS or the built-in webserver?

Comment: If it is installed, it is enabled in Control Panel > Turn Windows feature on or off >  Internet Information Services in Windows 7.

Comment: I suggest IIS Express: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038

Comment: @jao I can see IIS 7.5 Express in my control panel. Now what should I do to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your service is already running happily and using Windows Authentication, so it requires the calling application, your web site to also be using Windows Authentication.

When you try and add a reference, VS will start your site in the background using whichever web server is defined in Project Properties. You say that you are starting your site using the built-in web server (also known as Cassini or Webdev). You need to ensure that your site is using Windows Authentication. You do this from the service's Project Properties (right-click on the root folder and select Properties). In there you will see a Web tab which has an NTLM Authentication checkbox - make sure that is checked.

Also, make sure that you use:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows">
...
```

in your web.config.

However, if you want to use IIS itself, I assume you have it installed and know how to define a web application. Depending on which version of Windows you are running, you may or may not have IIS installed or it may not be installable (using Programs and Features from Control Panel). If you don't have IIS, you can install IIS Express from here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

After you have installed IIS and defined your application root, and pointed the directory to your local source folder, enable Windows (NTLM) Authentication for that web app/site. How you do that depends on which version of IIS you are running but it is normally by clicking on the Authentication icon. You probably need to disable Anonymous as well as enable Windows Authentication, so that all requests are forced into Windows authentication. For browsers that do not support automatic NTLM authentication, I also turn on Basic Forms authentication as well.

Once you have an IIS application defined, you can use that for debugging from Visual Studio instead of the built-in web server. You also do that from Project Properties by choosing 'Use Local IIS Server' and selecting the Url of the IIS site you created above. Alternatively, VS can create the IIS site definition for you if it doesn't yet exist.

Either of the above methods should ensure that when VS starts your site to add a reference, it will be using authentication, as well as at runtime. Note that you can add a reference manually, without the need for starting the site. Then you just need to make sure you have Windows authentication at runtime, as described above.